# How to set C++/CLI mode in Visual Studio Code 1.69?

Tags: visual-studio-code, c++-cli

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWYYS.png)Here's the code:

```
#using < system.drawing.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Drawing;

protected:
virtual Void Form1::OnPaint(PaintEventArgs ^ pe) override
{
    Graphics ^ g = pe->Graphics;
    Image ^ image = Image::FromFile("SampleImage.jpg");
    Form::ClientSize = image->Size;
    g->DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image->Size.Width, image->Size.Height);
}
```

The error text is ""#using" requires C++/CLI mode".

[adding pragma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGAFj.png)

[adding /clr in tasks.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGAFj.png)

Comment: Windows 10 Home.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options:

- Add `#pragma managed` on the top file line:

  ```
  #pragma managed
  #using < system.drawing.dll>
  // ...
  ```
- Add `/clr` to `args` in tasks.json

Comment: It didn't change anything: the error remained the same.